# How to disable TCP packets with overlapping data in Windows Server?

Tags: windows, tcp, windows-server-2016

Consider this short Wireshark packet capture on Windows Server 2016:

[image: Overlapping TCP packets]

### Frame-1

TCP Window Size of client (192.168.201.5) is 1504 bytes.

### Frame-5

TCP Server responded back with a packet (length 1083).

```
TCP Payload: 1029 bytes
TCP Seq No: 1
```

### Frame-6

Without waiting for acknowledgment of previous packet, server sent another packet (length 1414).

```
TCP Payload: 1360
TCP Seq No: 145
```

### Summary

So in order to maximise the payload transfer:

- Server sent `1..1029` bytes of data in first packet.
- server sent `145..1504` bytes of data in second packet.
- Effectively both packets contain `145..1029` bytes.

### Question

This server is talking to small devices whose TCP stack is not powerful enough to assemble the packets containing overlapping data. So the session fails (TCP reset in Frame-12).

Is there any way to configure Windows so that it sends simpler (non-overlapping) packets?

**EDIT**
You can download the [pcap file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/l3qo0cfxfcik4k6/serverfault.pcap?dl=1) for full details.

**EDIT-2**:

[Download pcap file of full session](https://www.dropbox.com/s/echea5dftkafat9/serverfault-full.pcap?dl=1) This session can be seen by applying a filter `tcp.port == 50002 and ip.addr == 192.168.201.5`

Comment: Could you please provide the full pcap and not just an image showing a few details of it? The image alone does not provide sufficient information to see what's going on.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich Sure. Attached now.

Comment: Your original PCAP file starts from frame 244, while the attached PCAP starts from frame #1. What is the difference between the PCAP files?

Comment: @TeroKilkanen Since apologies for confusion. Actually the original screenshot was of full session. In the pcap file, I exported only one session which changes the frame numbers. I have fixed the screenshot to match with pcap fie now.

Comment: The full session has important details to answer the question properly. My answer below is an educated guess what might be happening, but without the full PCAP I don't know if that is a valid guess.

Comment: These overlapping packets do not look like normal behavior for me. Is this really directly sniffed at the server and there is not something in between which might have fiddled with the packets? I.e. no firewall, not windows inside VM etc?

Comment: @SteffenUllrich It is sniffed directly on server so it is definitely originating from server.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen I have attached the pcap file of full session (and also the filter that you can apply to see this session)

Answer (score 2):

To me, it seems there are packets from two different TCP sessions in the dump. The sessions just seem to have same port numbers, which causes the RST behavior.

Frames 1-5 and 7-8 belong to the same session, while frame 6 is for some other session.

Does the client device use a random TCP port as the source port when opening connections?

Comment: These devices use GPRS communication. Communication provider does some sort of address and port translation. But I do see the same port being reused after some time (about a minute). Not sure if this can cause any issue.

Comment: As evident from the full pcap file, there are no other session for same address+port. This packet is definitely part of the same session. Please can you suggest anything?

Comment: Just a guess, it could be a bug in Windows TCP stack with small TCP window / segment sizes. Window size is 1504 bytes here, and MSS is 1360 bytes. 1504 - 1360 = 144, which is the SEQ difference between frames 5 and 6. Maybe Windows TCP stack works incorrectly when TCP window is less than 2xMSS.